# very slow mouse in virtualbox. how to fix it?

Tags: virtualbox

I have import an appliance in oracle virtualbox 5.1.14 to two PCs.
one of them it works properly, and the other the mouse and keyboard are very slow and turned to not working. How to fix this problem?

Comment: is the VM or host severely low on free RAM or CPU?

Comment: no the host ram is 6 GB and the guest ram is 2 GB with 4 processors to work

Comment: how about utilization? is the slow guest using 95%+ CPU?

Comment: yes it reaches to more than 95%  in CPU

Comment: but most of times is less than 90% in CPU utilization

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to make sure that you install Guest additions inside your system, it will help with mouse movement. As well as make sure that you enable virtualization in Bios. It exists under CPU features with different names like

**Intel Virtualization, Virtualization or vt_x**

Comment: that really helps

Comment: What do you mean by " install Guest additions inside your system" and "enable virtualization in bios" ? please be more pedagogical..

Answer (score 3):

Make sure mouse integration is enabled. If you have two mice pointers it’s not enabled. Clicking the mouse icon on settings tab fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your mouse icons inside your OS. I was using a Windows Guest and for some reason, the "typing" icon which looks like an "I" was super laggy any time it appeared.

All other mouse icons were normal speed. So I changed my mouse icon theme to "extra large" and viola! Speed is normal even on the "I" icon! A very strange solution but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve for MAC OS Catalina on Virtualbox by going to Settings -> USB -> Enable USB Controller and checkeck "USB 2.0 (OHCI + EHCI) Controller"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it help to *disable* the accelerated 3d support for the display.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).